# When rendering hair, it doesn't follow the particle edit path

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, particles, hair

I have Blender 2.69.

I have been following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VcOzFF27OLs) on Youtube.

The [.blend](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6xONZ2msgKHVzhfUFpJdUVWSTQ/edit?usp=sharing) file on google drive.

[image: this is my figure in the view port]

[image: this is my figure once rendered]

This is what it does...

Comment: Could you add your .blend file? It's not obvious what the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

The *Size* settings on the material are set too large, try setting the *Root* and *Tip* sizes in *Material Settings > Strand > Size* to smaller values:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's your hair's material, I couldn't find anything wrong with the particle system and created a new one, I only set the particle system to from emitter to hair, adjusted the length, and assigned the vertex-group for length.

After setting the matrial to index 2 (your hair color) this happened:

[image]

Creating a new material fixed the problem:

[image]

You should simply create a new material or comare the settings with default, probably you ticked some option by accident. If this alone doesn't help, remove and add the particle system.